# R: How to make a "factorial therefrom numeric v." demand from dataframe

Tags: r

I need some help! :)
What I would like to do in R is to make a command where I can just assign the numerical variables to the factorial variable and from there keep on working, something like:

```
AgeAlfalfaBand <- c(Band therefrom Age) #see table below
```

so I can do things like: Correlate "Band therefrom Age" with "Band therefrom Larvae"

Or is there an even easier way?

Table:

```
Farmer  Age [years]  Larvae [per m2]  
Band              2             1315  
Band              4              725  
Band              6               90  
Fechney           1              520  
Fechney           3              285  
Fechney           9               30  
Mulholland        2              725  
Mulholland        6               20
```

Thank you for helping me! Regards

Comment: It is not clear what you wanted.  Perhaps create a list of key/value pair, i.e. `setNames(as.list(df1$Age), df1$Farmer)` or it could be `split(df1$Age, df1$Farmer)` if the same elements of Farmer go as a single vector

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't  understand your solution ;)

The thing I want to know is how to assing a variable to another variable so I can work with it. For instance, I want to correlate the Age of the plant (Alfalfa) that the farmers produce with the number of Larvae (Alfalfa pest) per m2 of Alfalfa field. 

Like this: The Age of Alfalfa grown by Farmer X1 correlated with the no. of Larvae on the field of Farmer X1; 

Isn't there something like: Age$FarmerX1 ~ Larvae$FarmerX1 ?

Or is there an autom. way that R assigns all variables to one another? Maybe it's a biít clearer now? :) Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to subset your data by `Farmer` first. Then correlate `Age` and `Larvae` for each subset.

**Example:**

```
band <- x[x$Farmer == "Band", ]
with(band, plot(Larvae~Age, main="Band"))
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Edited:**

You can compare all `Age` and `Larvae` values as follows:

```
pairs(x$Age~x$Larvae, col = x$Farmer, pch = 16)
```

The `col` argument to pairs will plot the dots with a different color for every farmer. The `pch` argument will make the dots filled.

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks! This is a bit more to my liking!
Yet when I use this command it says the "$" is invalid for atomic vectors. Is there a possibility to do this with atomic vectors?

Or is it even possible to do such a graph for the entire table (that sort of links the Farmers with the Correlation of Age and Larvae?) Thanks again!

Comment: If you want to use $, you will have to convert your data to a dataframe like `as.data.frame(data)`. Updated answer with new graph.

Comment: Okay I did this; It worked out! Thank you! :)

Yet the farmer color didn't because R found a "-2" value so an error appeared; 
Also it only worked with with the atomic vector code: `pairs(x[Age_yrs]~x[Larvae_per_m²], pch = 16)`
Whatever...

Comment: Okay! I'll try that i guess!