# Treat variables as data_frame and other things

Tags: r, dataframe

I guess I have a problem in R. I have this data frame (see at the bottom); I imported it as a Import Dataset "Weevils" from Text; then I converted the data via
`as.data.frame(Weevils)` and `is.data.frame(Weevils) [1] TRUE` proved me it's a data frame yet I cannot use the $ operator because the variables were all "atomic vectors"; I tried this instead:

> `pairs(x[Age_yrs]~x[Larvae_per_m²], col= x[Farmer] pch = 16)`

but then this occured:

```
Error in plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : 
      numerische Farbe muss >= 0 sein, gefunden -2
```

which basically means that a negative value (for ther Farmer?) was found therefore so it cannot assign the colors to the outcome; All is supposed to look like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40829168/5987736 (Thanks to Carles Mitjans!)

yet what came out in my case when putting in `pairs(x[Age_yrs]~x[Larvae_per_m²], pch = 16)` was this plot: [Plot with negative values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIWfp.png) ; it has negative values, thus the colors cannto be assigned;

So my questions are: Why cannot the variables in the Weevils dataframe be treated as non-atomic vectors or why can't I use the $ and why are the values negative, what can I do so the values get positive? Thanks for helping me!

```
       Farmer Age_yrs Larvae_per_m²
1        Band       2          1315
2        Band       4           725
3        Band       6            90
4     Fechney       1           520
5     Fechney       3           285
6     Fechney       9            30
7  Mulholland       2           725
8  Mulholland       6            20
9       Adams       2           150
10      Adams       3           225
11  Forrester       1           455
12  Forrester       3            75
13 Bilborough       2           850
14 Bilborough       3           650
```

Comment: Check the `str(Weevils)`.  Also, you may need quotes `x["Age_yrs"]`

Comment: `'data.frame': 14 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Farmer       : Factor w/ 6 levels "Adams","Band",..: 2 2 2 4 4 4 6 6 1 1 ...
 $ Age_yrs      : int  2 4 6 1 3 9 2 6 2 3 ...
 $ Larvae_per_m²: int  1315 725 90 520 285 30 725 20 150 225 ...`

Does that mean I have to put Farmer as factor, but how would I do that? (I'm sorry I'm already too confused and I have to enter my homework this evening --)

Comment: The `pairs(x[2:3], col = x$Farmer, pch= 16)` works based on your example, x$Farmer is `factor`

Comment: `pairs(x[2:3], col = x$Farmer, pch= 16)`
Error in x$Farmer : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
`pairs(x[2:3], col = x[Farmer], pch= 16)`
Error in pairs.default(x[2:3], col = x[Farmer], pch = 16) : 
  nur eine Spalte im Argument zu 'pairs' (only one column in the argument for "pairs"

?? Maybe you know something?

Comment: The `str(x)` is `str(x)#
'data.frame':   14 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Farmer       : Factor w/ 6 levels "Adams","Band",..: 2 2 2 4 4 4 6 6 1 1 ...
 $ Age_yrs      : int  2 4 6 1 3 9 2 6 2 3 ...
 $ Larvae_per_m²: int  1315 725 90 520 285 30 725 20 150 225 ...`  It works for me

Comment: can you give a reproducible example please?

Comment: @Hardik
I have this data frame (as above); Now I would like to correlate Age and Larvae/m² and find out if there is any difference per farmer; 
The thing is I cannot proceed with my work because the basic things do not function; I would actually like see correlation between the variables "within" each `factor` (each Farmer);  I have the whole issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40828609/r-how-to-make-a-factorial-therefrom-numeric-v-demand-from-dataframe/40829168#40829168
but nothing works for me cuz R doesn't recognize my variables as to be able to operate them with $; :/ Thnx!

Comment: I actually have the research question here: Dunno if it helps: 4. The larvae of weevils are a pest in alfalfa. It was, however, hypothesized that weevil 
populations decline as the alfalfa stand gets older and you are asked to assess this 
statistically.  You  receive  data  from  different  farms  that  differ  inter  alia  in  their  pest 
management strategies. Can you find the hypothesized relationship? Plot your results 
appropriately.

Comment: Nevermind, now it worked!!! -> `pairs(x[Age_yrs]~x[Larvae_per_m²], col= Farmer, pch = 16)` Thanks!